# Cannot redeclare class in Drupal GraphQL plugin

Tags: graphql, drupal-8

While following this tutorial

> http://dirtystylus.com/2018/09/12/graphql-adding-fields-to-types-in-drupal-8/

I am trying to create a new plugin for the GraphQL field in my app. However, I am getting the "Cannot redeclare class" fatal error although I am pretty sure there is no other place with BackgroundImage class in my app.

This is my `dds/src/Plugin/GraphQL/Fields/FieldPluginBase.php` file, where `dds` is the custom module's directory:

```
namespace Drupal\dds\Plugin\GraphQL\Fields;

use Drupal\graphql\GraphQL\Execution\ResolveContext;
use Drupal\graphql\Plugin\GraphQL\Fields\FieldPluginBase;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;

/**
 * A simple field that returns the background image.
 *
 * For simplicity reasons, this example does not utilize dependency injection.
 *
 * @GraphQLField(
 *   id = "backgroundimage",
 *   type = "String",
 *   name = "backgroundimage",
 *   nullable = true,
 *   multi = false
 * )
 */

class BackgroundImage extends FieldPluginBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function resolveValues($value, array $args, ResolveContext $context, ResolveInfo $info) {
    // parent::resolveValues($value, $args, $context, $info);

    $fid = \Drupal::config('dds.settings')->get('background_image');
    yield $fid;
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is: `Fatal error: Cannot declare class Drupal\dds\Plugin\GraphQL\Fields\BackgroundImage, because the name is already in use in /app/web/web/modules/custom/dds/src/Plugin/GraphQL/Fields/FieldPluginBase.php on line 33`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the filename. After changing it to `BackgroundImage.php` everything works fine.